# Why is Django rendering one of my app's templates as plain text

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a blog development in Django and there are different categories of posts or articles on **category_list.html** which have been created using ORM library and to each category i have added some articles using ORM library with the help of category slug which are rendered on category_view.html and **problem is that list of categories are shown perfectly on category_list.html after adding from admin panel of django and when I click on any category name(contains get_absolute_url link), it takes me perfectly to category_view.html page but on category_view.html, data is shown in the form of text means renders the complete content of category_view.html in the form of plain text**. All other templates are getting rendered by django perfectly but what is the reason that category_view.html is getting rendered as plain text? Please help me

```
 def category_list(request,category_slug=None):
              category=None
              categories=CategoryList.objects.all()
           # article=Article.objects.all()
               return render(request,'category_list.html',{'categories':categories})

    def category_view(request,category_slug):
               category=get_object_or_404(CategoryList,slug=category_slug)
               article=Article.objects.filter(category=category)
               return render(request,'category_view.html',{'category':category},{'article':article})
```

My url.py contains the following urls:

```
path("",views.index),
path('category',views.category_list, name='category_list'),
path('<slug:category_slug>',views.category_view, name='story_by_category'),
```

This is link in category_list.html which takes me to category_view.html

```
<div class="row py-3">
        {%for c in categories%}
        <div class="col-lg col-12 homeimg" id="img1">
          
           <h5><a href="{{c.get_absolute_url}}">{{c.name}}</a></h5>
          <img class="secimg border-info" src="{{c.image_url|default_if_none:'#'}}" alt="gameplay 
  videos">
          
        </div>
        {%endfor%}
        
    </div>
```

Comment: you send two context dicts I guess this is the mistake. you should habe "category" and "article" in one dict. check out django docs on how to send multiple things in the context. Right now the "aritcle" argument is seen as "content_type". I dont know if that fixes your error but you should fix it anyway...

Comment: @hansTheFranz Thank you very much. I didn't notify this silly mistake I made. Now, I corrected the passed dict after seeing your comment and it worked Fine. Thanks once again.